# VBA, get 3 worksheets by name, given a file name

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get certain worksheets by name within an Excel file.
Basically my Excel file has 7 worksheets, but I want only 3 of these, by name.

Because I am looping through a folder to get all my files, all I have is the filename and path, so I want to pass the filename to this Sub and get an instance of type 'Worksheets'

How do I do this ?

Comment: I don't get why someone would cast a negative vote on this. This is a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand how looping through files relate to retrieving sheets by name, but you use an `Array`-typed index to query `Worksheets` for a subset of items:

```
dim wb as Workbook
set wb = Workbooks.Open("file.xls")
wb.Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select
```